# dont understand the cassandra jmx mbean metrics

Tags: cassandra

there are several questions about cassandra jmx mbean.

1.how the attribute mean calculate?
I have monitored metrics with jconsole.and I see the value of write mbean.
there is an attribute Mean in write MBean.and I dont know how to count the value in cassandra as I doubt that the value is right
make a junit test,

```
 Timer latency=new Timer()
 latency.update(timeTaken, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I input three values,0,1,2
and expected the mean value is 1000microseconds.but the fact is 1131.752microseconds,which confuse me a lot.

3.there are mean attribute,  50thPercentile attribute,and etc.
but I cannot get the instant value,when I want to see the quick change in cluster.all of these attributes cannot indicate the changes

Answer (score 1):

Important to note that the latencies are estimates, not exact. It cannot store every latency that has occurred or it will run out of memory. So it keeps an approximate reservoir or histogram of all the latencies (depending on version) that it uses to calculate the statistics. Assuming your over C* 2.2, it stores a histogram of the latencies and can calculate approximate mean, min, max and percentiles within a given error %.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/EstimatedHistogram.java#L227 is the mean calculation. Since each bucket represents a range of latencies it uses the high end, so it always will be at worst, higher than the actual latency.

Before 2.2 this was kept differently (see http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/ for details).

Aside: Mean is a pretty bad statistic to go by for latencies so shouldn't put too much stock in it, percentiles are better to look at.

Comment: cannot agree more with your opinion.but percenties also take the estimates value,not exact value.why do your think percenties are better to look at

Comment: latencies tend to not have a normal distribution, so things like mean and std dev give you a less then ideal view of what it is like. Since there can be pretty long tails things like the 99th and 99.9th are more of what is relevant to app developers. Consider: "1 of every 100 requests takes 100ms but the rest are sub 1ms" vs "the average is 0.1ms".